# Screenshot to report inappropriate adsense ads

Tags: screenshot

In my website, I have some adsense blocks. Sometimes the show inappropriate ads. I already have some filters, but they don't block everything.

I need to allow the visitors to report these ads in this way: They click a button that exists below the ad, the browser asks for authorization, the script takes a screenshot of the page and sends it to the server.

I imagine something like the flash authorization dialog when someone tries to use her microphone or webcam in a website.

Comment: Hi! Flash is not allowed to take a picture of something else than itself. I remove the tag "flash" from your question since I know this is not an option.
You may try exploring the DOM in Javascript...

Comment: @Kodiak - Even if the answer is "you cannot", it's still a Flash question.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario then the question won't be read by anyone able to help... the "flash" tag is only there because mossaab made an analogy with a window generated by Flash in a another context.

Comment: @Kodiak - I don't understand when you say Flash is not allowed to take a picture of something else than itself. In this page : http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/photoCam.jsf , Flash takes a picture from my webcam.

Comment: @mossaab yes, and your webcam is displayed in and by the flash itself. you can capture something outside the flash. It excludes html next to, behind or on top of an swf.

Comment: AFAIK, one option is to load the add in a custom swf and draw contents into a BitmapData so you can send it to the server when a user rports an ad. The main issue is you need to either have access to the swf from a different domain (via a crossdomain.xml policy file) or cache the swf on your server first (using php or any server side language you want), then load it and draw the contents into BitmapData if the user reports it.

Comment: @Kodiak - OK. I deleted the Flash tag.
George - Isn't there any code somewhere that does that?
BTW, I don't want the code to rebuild the page, because a different ad may show up. I want the current screen to be captured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that there is NO solution yet to this question. The best thing one could do is to rebuild the page with tools such as [html2canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/). However, new ads may show up instead of the original ones.

Answer (score 0):

Try to get a copy of banner directory, so you'll get a direct link to the banner....
id="google_ads_frame1"
The HTML code looks like this:

```
<img src="/pagead/imgad?id=CICAgICQ3vWx7wEQ2AUYWjIISwklo8Ydels" border="0" width="728" onload="(function(that){function c(b,a,d){if(b&amp;&amp;a)if(b.height&gt;0){a.style.top=0;a.style.visibility='visible'}else setTimeout(function(){c(b,a,d*2)},d)}c(that,document.getElementById('abgc'),10);})(this);">
```

- src="/pagead/imgad?id=CICAgICQ3vWx7wEQ2AUYWjIISwklo8Ydels"

  1. You can try the get get the adchoice (small blue triangle at right above your adsense banners) button, and get your information about the ad from the HTML script...
     The id of this button: id="abgc"
     You can get extract the website data using javascript...
     The code looks like this: